# Riverpod doesn't notify listeners

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I am writing a quiz app to learn riverpod , here my providers :

```
final questionProvider = Provider((ref) => shuffled(Statics.q).sublist(0, 10)); // holding the List of questions (Exam consists of 10 questions)

final indexProvider = StateProvider((ref) => 0); // Holding the index of the question (0-9)

final questionStateProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider.autoDispose<QStateNotifier, Question>((ref) {
  final _index = ref.watch(indexProvider).state; // Index of the question
  final _questions = ref.read(questionProvider); // List of questions
  return QStateNotifier(_questions[_index]);
});
```

Here is part of my UI .

```
class AnswerBar extends HookWidget { // This Widget shows the clicked letters(via CharPadButton)
  AnswerBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var _question = useProvider(questionStateProvider);
    if (_question.answer.length == 2) {
      print(_question.hashCode);
      return Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          AnswerBubble(char: _question.answerBar[0]), // AnswerBubbles are where i show the clicked chars that coming from CharPadButtons.
          AnswerBubble(char: _question.answerBar[1]),
        ],
      );
    }
```

Here is the button that i am getting the character inputs for the asked question.

```
class CharPadButtons extends HookWidget { // Every CharPadButton has a Text Widget as a child which contains a letter.
  CharPadButtons({Key? key, required this.char}) : super(key: key);
  final String char;
  bool isTapped = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _questionNotifier = useProvider(questionStateProvider.notifier);
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        if (isTapped == false) {
          _questionNotifier.addAnswerBar(char);

          isTapped = true;
        }
      },
```

Here is my StateNotifier :

```
class QStateNotifier extends StateNotifier<Question> {
  QStateNotifier(Question state) : super(state);

  void addAnswerBar(String char) {
    var temp = [...state.answerBar];
    temp.insert(state.currentAnswerBarIndex, char);
    var tempCurrentBarIndex = state.currentAnswerBarIndex + 1;

    state = Question(
        description: state.description,
        answer: state.answer,
        answerBar: temp,
        currentAnswerBarIndex: tempCurrentBarIndex);
    print(state.answerBar); // I put it to see if answerBar is updated correctly and yes.
  }
```

Question model :

```
class Question extends Equatable {
  final String description;
  final List<String> answer;
  final List<String> answerBar;
  final List<String> randomBar;
  final int currentAnswerBarIndex;

  Question({
    required this.description,
    required this.answer,
    this.answerBar = const ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
    this.currentAnswerBarIndex = 0,
  }) : randomBar = shuffleit([...answer, ...randLetterChoice(answer.length)]);

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [answerBar,currentAnswerBarIndex];
}
```

Despite of the answerBar is updating itself correctly, UI is not rebuilt.StateNotifier's State (which is a Question object) is updated at every click on the CharPadButtons widget. But _question.answerBar[index] is not updating , i don't understand why listeners are not notified and UI is not rebuilt.

Comment: Can you add a bit of information about your model Question and QStateNotifier to understand how you update your state

Comment: updated it , can you have a look again? , By the way , i am using a very nested widget structure , maybe this is the problem.

Comment: You said state is upsetting correctly but not the UI, can you confirm in AnswerBar that your provider updated? That AnswerBubble actually received a different char

Comment: I put a print() statement at the first line of build() of AnswerBar and saw that widget is built only once(only at first start ) although i have pressed the CharPadButtons and state.AnswerBar was updated, my app is not rebuilt anymore except the first start.

Comment: I don't know the Key concept of Flutter(Globalkey,UniqueKey) , I'm not sure but i have a feeling like problem is somehow about the keys, because of so many rows and columns existing(which compose of multiple same objects) and , so many distinct nested HookWidgets .

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem as far as I can tell by seeing the code, AnswerBar build method should update when the hookElement use provider changes, what you mention could be a problem with AnswerBubble because of the row with many children, but right now it's the parent widget not updating the data, have you tried a breakpoint in AnswerBar with debugger and see if it changes? Or are you completely sure there isn't another provider with the same name by mistake?

Comment: Thanks for your answers.There is nothing to do.